# What can be the -dontwarn rule for this warning on proguard android?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

This is the error message I am getting:

```
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
at ...
```

The complete error log is [here](https://pastebin.com/kq0Vp0eq).

I have tried
`-dontwarn org.gradle.tooling.BuildException` and
`-dontwarn org.gradle.**`.

When I am putting `-dontwarn **` then the project builds successfully. But I don't want the use this global rule. I want to use a specific rule. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I was using outdated proguard-rules for third-party libraries like okhttp3, gson.